# How to get linkedin access token with django python?

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api, social-auth-app-django

I am working on an django (python) application that needs that access token from Linkedin API. I tried the following library `social-auth-app-django` but it didn't help me because I do not need only to sign in, I want to store that access token in the below database to use the token in the future features of the app and I am not sure how to print it or get it from `social-auth-app-django`.

```
----------------------------------------
id | username | password | LinkedinToken
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: aren't their docs not helping ? I used django-allauth and it is very straight-forward with it. May be try that ?

Comment: I will give it a try. Does django-allauth create an object after authentification? Then could I acces the token like user(django-allauth object).accest_tokken?

Comment: Yes you can access

Comment: @LokeshSanapalli need some help now. I did the connection between my app and linkedin, but the problem is that i do not know how to access the token. Could you help me please?

Comment: if you open your database in any client, you'll see the tables, there you can find!

Comment: There was no access_token. But I solved the case. I did without any django packages. Thanks for your time.